# Loading HTML into a Javascript Variable without AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a website in which the total dynamic content is very small (say < 50k).  The site itself is just a collection of 5-10 pages of mostly vanilla HTML.  To separate the headers and such from the rest of the content, I'd normally use AJAX (so that AJAX queries grab the relevant HTML every time the user clicks on something, or beforehand).

In this case, since the dynamic content is so small, it seems unnecessary (and wasteful) to do 10 AJAX queries to load everything.  The question is: **"Is there a server-side way to load javascript variables with text from other files without web requests?"**

The reason I ask is that it would be very easy for me to do this by hand, by just making a .js file with the variables loaded:

```
var page1 = "<p>Here's some web content!</p>"
var page2 = "<p>And some more!</p>"
```

Problem solved.  Except that now my content is mixed up with my Javascript, and I have to worry about escaping quotes, and I'm in indentation hell, and so on.  I could certainly do server-side scripting (in php or ruby or whatever), but that seems a little heavyweight for such a simple thing.

Is there a cleaner way this can be done server-side?  I **will** take "no" for an answer, here, if that's the best that can be done.

Comment: It sounds like a job for PHP and GET headers, but I'll sit back and see some of the suggestions.

Comment: are you using a server side processing framework?  .net? php? java? node.js?

Comment: An alternative solution would be putting all your HTML snippets to a hidden div/iframe server-side, and then read their `innerHTML` on the client. Or more elaborate: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Comment: @Jason - I could probably deploy whatever I wanted.  I'm familiar with all the ones you've mentioned, but the idea was to stay away from server-side scripting as much as possible.  Again, this might be asking too much.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - Interesting idea.  I don't know if I'll go for it, but certainly a good thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a PHP extension file as javascript via `<script type="text/javascript" src="myJavaScriptGlobals.php"></script>`

Have PHP dynamically pull all your data together, and output valid JavaScript.

```
echo '
var page1 = "'.str_replace('"','\"',$page1ContentFromFOPEN).'"; // escape double quotes
';
```

This makes it so you don't need to do any http requests after page load and achieving instant content load from assigned variables like `page1`.

Updated to only strip double quotes

Comment: What would be the purpose of `stripslashes` here?

Comment: I updated to remove it since stripslashes also does add slashes on other characters. \" would be ignored inside a double quoted string, the strip is escaped in javascript when its used in context.

Comment: `stripslashes` does rather do the opposite of what you’ve suggested: It removes the escaping `\ ` character.

Comment: Sorry, typed out the wrong thing initially regardless, (I meant addslashes, the provided solution I updated a few mins ago is what I intended) Thanks for correcting my gaffe!

Comment: You should better use `json_encode` if possible as a string containing `\"` would slip through possibly allowing code injection or at least unexpected behavior.

Comment: @MattLo - This is (roughly) the best solution I could think of when I asked the question, boiling down to "Use a server side script to generate these variables."  A fine solution, and only minimal scripting required.  I'll accept for now and see if anyone has anything better later on.